# Get height from getBoundingClientRect and apply it as a style with alpine.js

Tags: alpine.js

I am learning alpine.js and getting the hang of the basic x-show and class binding.
Now I'm getting into some slightly more complicated things.
For instance, here I'm getting the height of the div and logging it to the console:

```
<div x-data="{ imgHeight: $el.getBoundingClientRect().height }"
     x-init="console.log(imgHeight)">
</div>
```

This works fine but now I would like to take the value `imgHeight` and use it as a height class.

This is where I get a bit confused, I can't do something like `:class="imgHeight"` that doesn't make sense since the imgHeight value isn't a class.
Something like this also doesn't work `:style="{ height: 'imgHeight'px }`.

So my sense is that it has to do with getters and setters, I need to set the value of Image height as a class and get the class name and bind that. If thats the case I'm no sure how to structure that. Would love to get some guidance on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point you are missing is that everything inside an Alpine.js directive is just JavaScript, so you can just write `height: imgHeight + 'px'` or with template literals:

```
:style="{height: `${imgHeight}px`}
```

You are free to write as much JS code as you want inside a directive. Refactoring them into getters and other methods makes sense when they become too long to read them inplace and/or you want to reuse a component. But for these small tasks writing JS directly into Alpine.js directives is perfectly fine.

Comment: ok I see, I'm not familiar with template literals any reason  would do that over ```height: imgHeight + 'px'```

Comment: It's like Python's f-string. If you have many variables, then you don't have to write that many quotation marks, it's more readable in my opinion. But both methods are fine.